# Are there reports of Google Cloud Print usage?

Tags: google-cloud-print

I have a shared printer that is accessible to Google Cloud Print services.  I would like to enable this usage for our users, however, I need to be able to run reports to see who printed what, when. We allocate printer supply costs based on usage, and as far as I can tell, Google doesn't give me a way to get any data about past print jobs other than the name of a job, it's status, and when it happened.  What about who did it?  I know that Google knows their email address!  What about how many pages it was, or what settings were used (b/w vs. color, 1- vs. 2-sided, etc).

I hope I am just missing it.

Also, if perhaps this information is not available through Google's UI but **is** available through any developer-aimed APIs, that would be great info, because I can certainly get at it from that angle if necessary.

Any help or advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I used a different approach then your. I used as a base this library https://github.com/escube/GoogleCloudSpooler i developed and created a web service from it. People can login in my system, upload the file to my server and i log everything there. My service upload to google cloud printer. This is the only way to keep control on how and what peole use my printers.
I should  clean my web code in the next code and maybe publish on git hub if someone thinks that can be useful.